# aws rds binlog file missing

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

Sorry this question could be very basic but I couldn't find anything to fix the issue.

I have an aws rds and when I try to get my binlog list it's only show me the 2 latest one.

```
SHOW BINARY LOGS;  
'mysql-bin-changelog.008387', '463'
'mysql-bin-changelog.008388', '120'
```

it's always show me the 2 latest one 
is that means the other files purged ? if yes how can I prevent to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDS purges binlogs as soon as they are no longer needed by any managed RDS replicas.

There's a stored procedure on each instance that allows you to change this behavior.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql_rds_set_configuration.html